# Exporting data from datatable to excel in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to export data from datatable to excel and current timestamp at the bottom in the excel. How i can add current timestamp in the excel.

Comment: There's a library called EPPlus. You can add it with a nuget package. It's the easiest way to create Excel from a .NET application.

Answer (score 1):

I use EPPlus. Here is a generic function I created for my application. The function takes a generic `List<T>` and exports to Excel. The class (T) property names become the headers in the Excel spreadsheet.

```
public const string ExcelMimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

public FileContentResult ExportToExcel<T>(string reportName, IEnumerable<T> reportLines) where T : class
{
    MemberInfo[] info = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(c => (MemberInfo)c).ToArray();
    ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(reportLines, true, TableStyles.Light1, BindingFlags.GetProperty, info);
    string fileName = $"{reportName}_{DateTime.Now:ddMMyyyy}.xlsx".Replace(" ", "-");
    return File(package.GetAsByteArray(), ExcelMimeType, fileName);
}
```